# Como recuperar data do SQL Server corretamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Eu criei um **CRUD** simples usando o **ASP.NET MVC** e eu posso salvar meus registros normalmente. Se eu olhar na base de dados, minha data (**DataCriacao**) foi armazenada assim:

> 2017-06-01 00: 01: 23.750

Mas quando tento **editar** o mesmo registro com um método assíncrono criado pelo MVC Scaffolding, todos os campos da tabela são recuperados, mas a **DataCriacao** parece ser nula:

> 01/01/2000 00:00:00

Então (obviamente) recebo um erro:

> A conversão de um tipo de dados datetime2 para um tipo de dados
>   datetime resultou em um valor fora do alcance.

Esse é o método gerado:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ArtigoId,Titulo,Texto,DataPublicacao,UltimaModificacao,UsuarioModificacao,DataCriacao,UsuarioCriacao")] Artigo artigo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(artigo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(artigo);
}
```

Após o problema eu fiz algumas pesquisas e mudei o campo no banco de dados para `datetime2(0-7)` no EF Code First fazendo isso na minha model:

```
[DisplayName("Data de Criação")]
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
```

Isso não corrigiu o problema, apenas fez com que o campo aceitasse a data **01/01/2000 00:00:00**.

Como devo recuperar a data corretamente? Devo usar datetime ou datetime2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorreu por que removi meu campo da View e não tem nada haver com o formato da data no SQL Server.

Coloquei o campo de volta na **View** como **readonly**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataCriacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataCriacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataCriacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

A busca do campo no BD é feita no método GET:

```
// GET: Artigos/Edit/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Artigo artigo = await db.Artigoes.FindAsync(id);
    if (artigo == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(artigo);
}
```

O método que postei era o POST após o submit do meu botão para salvar as alterações e não eram feitas buscas na base de dados.

Comment: Só uma dica, evite gravar data e hora junto, se precisar, grave separado, assim você pode evitar problema futuros relacionados a consulta de dados.